# Unity OnCollisionStay2D giving error: "PlayerMovement.cs(45,44): error CS1001: Identifier expected"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a simple 2D game in Unity, and I'm trying to make it so my character can only jump if it's touching the ground. Here's my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float movementSpeed = 5.0f;
    [SerializeField] private bool isGrounded = false;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        move();
        jump();
    }

    private void move()
    {
        float move = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(movementSpeed * move * Time.deltaTime, rb.velocity.y);
    }

    private void jump()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGrounded == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("jump");
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D, col)
    {
        if(col.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
        {
            isGrounded = true;
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D, col)
    {
        if(col.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
        {
            isGrounded = false;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, it gives me this error: "PlayerMovement.cs(45,44): error CS1001: Identifier expected"

I have tried using Collider2D instead of Collision2D in the OnCollisionStay, but that won't work either. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What do you think this method prototype means?  `void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D, col)`. Do you actually have two separate parameters?

Answer (score 0):

`(Collision2D, col)` change to `(Collision2D col)`

```
void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D col)
        {
            if(col.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
            {
                isGrounded = true;
            }
        }

        void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D col)
        {
            if(col.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
            {
                isGrounded = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you Tim! That worked perfectly, I guess I just wasn't focused enough to realize I had a comma in there.